# How to create an array of structs in main() when struct definition is in a header file?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, header-files

I am creating a program that takes bookstore inventory and each individual item like the ISBN and author is in a struct called Books. Since there will be multiple books within this inventory, I want to create an array of the Books struct. Because of an outside requirement beyond my control, the struct definition must be in the header file where my class resides and the array of structs must be declared within main().

Here is the struct definition in the header file functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Books
{
        int ISBN;
        string Author;
        string Publisher;
        int Quantity;
        double Price;
};
```

Now I try to create the array of structs back in main(). Note that it allows me to create a variable from the struct Books, but not an array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int MAX_SIZE = 100, size, choice;
        functions bookstore;
        Books novels;
        Books booklist[MAX_SIZE];
}
```

**When I do this, I get the following compiler error**

*bookstore.cpp:11:16: error: variable length array of non-POD element
 type 'Books'
         Books booklist[MAX_SIZE];*

Why am I getting such an error when trying to declare an array of structs from an outside struct, but not a variable from the same outside struct?

Comment: If you get errors about non-POD element types, you're using C++, not C.

Comment: I think in C++ you can't have a variable_name as a array size for a VLA. It has to be a constant `int max = 100; int a[max];` is not allowed whereas `#define max 100 int a[max];` should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare MAX_SIZE as a const int and it should work.  The issue is that the size of the array has to be known at compile time (it has to be a compile time constant). An int can be changed during runtime while a const int (or a define) cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard does not support variable length arrays.  If you need variable length array functionality, use `vector<Books>` instead.

G++ allows VLAs as an extension to standard C++.  However, you cannot initialize VLAs in C, nor in G++'s dialect of C++.  So the elements of a VLA cannot have (non-trivial) constructors.  And the error message is telling you that:

```
variable length array of non-POD element type 'Books' Books booklist[MAX_SIZE];
```

You have a VLA because `MAX_SIZE` is not `const int MAX_SIZE = 100`.  You can't create a VLA of type `Books` because the `string` members have constructors (are not POD — Plain Old Data — types), and hence there's a non-trivial constructor for the type `Books`.

The simplest fix is to use:

```
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    int size;
    int choice;
```

Or use:

```
std::vector<Books> booklist;
```

Answer (score 1):

While declaring the structure you have to give like this.

```
struct Books booklist[MAX_SIZE];
```

Or else make the typedef in `headerfile`.

```
typedef struct Books
{
    int ISBN;
    string Author;
    string Publisher;
    int Quantity;
    double Price;
}Books;
```

---

Make the value of `MAX_SIZE` like this.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100
```

Comment: While `MAX_SIZE` is not a constant integer, this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

---

Regarding [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array):

- **If your code is `C++`** <sub>(This question)</sub>

AFAIK, there is nothing in `C++` standard as VLA support. Maybe `std::vector` will help.

**Solution:** For this code, you can change the `int MAX_SIZE = 100` to a `#define` statement, like `#define MAX_SIZE 100` or, make `MAX_SIZE` of type `const int`.

---

- **If your code is `C`** <sub>(As tagged earlier)</sub>

Point to note: As per your code, `Books` is not a data type, `struct Books` is.

So, use either of below:

- use `struct Books` in your code
- use `typedef struct  Books Books;` and then use `Books` as you've used in your code.

Also, as far as `C` standard is concerned, VLA is introduced in `C99` standard. You have to enforece the standard by supplying `--std=c99` with the `gcc`.

Comment: The code is C++, not C — witness the headers, the `using namespace std;` etc.  (Yes, the question was once tagged with C too, but that was a mistake.)

Comment: I would put sub-headings like `### If your code is C` before the C material, and `### If your code is C++` before the C++ material, but the code was already C++, so the C information, although accurate, isn't really relevant.  The C++ suggestions are OK.

Comment: Note that in C++, `Books` is a type once `struct Books {` has been parsed.  Your opening paragraphs are part of your C spiel.

Answer (score 0):

Just conver the following line to define

```
int MAX_SIZE = 100
```

So the solution would be

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100
```

Comment: Ugh!  `const int MAX_SIZE = 100;` would be way better; `enum { MAX_SIZE = 100 };` would be better.  Avoid `#define` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers below
a. I think it is a typo, the header file must contain `#endif` statement.
b. To create an array on stack, the array size must be a `const` , try changing `MAX_SIZE` to `const int MAX_SIZE = 100`.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using typedef, u need to specify the type as `struct <struct_name>`

```
int main()
{
    int MAX_SIZE = 100, size, choice;
    struct Books novels;
    struct Books booklist[MAX_SIZE];
}
```